# google analytics 4 "sign in with user id" field doesn't tell if the the user_id is set

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm new to google analytics, and I have a few questions about the meaning of a few default fields given in the events table.

The user_id field, is clearly the field that displays the user_id that my app/website generate when the user logs in.
If that is the case, the it makes sense that the  "sign in with user id" field will tell whether the event has a user_id attached to it. 
However, when looking at the data, in many cases the user_id is set for the event, but the "sign in with user id" is unset. It may also go the other way around - "sign in with user id" is set to 'yes', but the user_id is unset. 
How does this make sense?

Thanks,
Nimrod,

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  and describe any issues you are having  with your current solution.   If your question ins not programming related you may want to try https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The code that does the login ?